# Find similar phrases in a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, similarity

I am using Pandas to work on a dataframe that has a column with the name of companies.

For each company name, several versions of it are available. df is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],'company name':['name1', ' Name1 LTD', 'name1, ltd.','name 1 LT.D.',' name2 p.p.c', 'name2 ppc.']})
```

I was wondering if there is a simple way to find similar names and assign a unique id to them? For the example above, I would like to get something like:

```
dg = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','a','a','e','e'],'company name':['name1', ' Name1 LTD', 'name1, ltd.','name 1 LT.D.',' name2 p.p.c', 'name2 ppc.']})
```

Thanks,

Comment: The task here would be to standardize `company name`'s. Mapping a unique id to each company name is the easy part, what you would need to do is clean your data, that will be the tough part.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I've done is use regex or a function that processes the raw strings that strips out all the extra like ltd and arbitrary special characters. Then create a processed string that is their "true name" and create an index of id's based on the "true name".

Or you can use fuzzywuzzy to find the distance between two strings and build a candidate set of matches and build an index of unique names based on match scores.

i.e.

```
def clean_str(x):
    x2 = x.lower()
    x2 = x2.replace('.', '')
    return x2
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried both "re" and "fuzzywuzzy" modules. However, I was not able to get what I wanted. My file has about 1,000,000 rows, while there should only be ~ 90,000 unique names in this column. Not sure how to do this in an automated way. I want python to read the column from the first row. If it finds a new name (for the first time) (e.g. in row 10) keep it, but if it (e.g. the one for row 120) is similar to e.g. row 10, replace the name in row 120 with name in row 10.

Comment: @Mohsen, I believe what he is saying is you must "clean" and "standardize" company names with regex.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your problem, like any programming problem, needs to be broken down into smaller pieces. I will break this down step by step as I understood it, AND as I would approach it.

**Step 1.** Clean(make uniform) your `company name` values. Here is a good article on [data
    cleansing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cleansing) and why it
    is important.

**Step 2.** Map your `id` based on unique company names(this step is easy once step 1 is done)

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],'company_name':['na,me1', ' Name1 LTD', 'name1, ltd.','name 1 LT.D.',' name2 p.p.c', 'name2 ppc.']})
```

**Step 1.**
Clean it by using `extract` with `regex`
*keep in mind that below `regex` only captures the small sample you provided and you may need to design the pattern to work with your full dataset*

```
df['new_company_name'] = (df['company_name']
                         .str.lower()                    # lowercase to standardize
                         .str.replace(' |,','')          # remove extra characters, this may vary for your full dataset
                         .str.extract(r'^(\w+\d{1})'))   # pattern to extract the vital part of the name, this also will vary based on your data

print(df)

  id  company_name new_company_name
0  a         name1            name1
1  b     Name1 LTD            name1
2  c   name1, ltd.            name1
3  d  name 1 LT.D.            name1
4  e   name2 p.p.c            name2
5  f    name2 ppc.            name2
```

**Step 2**
It is advisable to use numerical values rather than `str` because of performance

*Option 1 using `groupby()` with `ngroup()`*

```
df['new_id'] = df.groupby('new_company_name').ngroup()
```

*Option 2 using `zip()`, `dict()`, and then `map()`*

```
unique_names = df.new_company_name.unique()
mapper = dict(
    zip(unique_names,
        [name_id for name_id in range(len(unique_names))]
    )
)
df['new_id'] = df['new_company_name'].map(mapper)
```

Same result for *Option 1* or *Option 2*

```
print(df)

  id  company_name new_company_name  new_id
0  a         name1            name1       0
1  b     Name1 LTD            name1       0
2  c   name1, ltd.            name1       0
3  d  name 1 LT.D.            name1       0
4  e   name2 p.p.c            name2       1
5  f    name2 ppc.            name2       1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It helps a lot. I have to find the pattern in my data then.

Comment: Yes that will make searching through and making id's to the data a lot easier.